# Use plugin configuration of subshops in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

How can i get the config value of an sales-channel?

I am doing this:

```
$this->systemConfigService->get('pluginName.config.enable')
```

but this call returned only the All Sales Channels config value.

How can I get the config value of a particular sales channel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument of the `get` method takes the `id` of a `sales_channel` entity.

```php
public function get(string $key, ?string $salesChannelId = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can always write the 2nd parameter as

```
$this->systemConfigService->get('YourPluginName.config.YourConfig', $context->getSalesChannelId())
```

where $context can change depending how you defined it in your method.